# Multiple rows with null values - i want one row with not null

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

My query result below:

```
ID            desc             Year   pid
0006845503    tes1             null   null
0006845503    null             2017   null      
0006845503    null             null    90   
0006845503    null             null    null
```

I want to show these results:

```
ID              desc               year    pid
0006845503      TEST1              2017    90
```

Answer (score 3):

If a value for a column appear only once(only one value available) , then simple group by should do the task :

```
SELECT t.id,t.year,t.code,MAX(t.desc) as desc,MAX(t.year) as year,MAX(t.pid) as pid
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.id,t.year,t.code
```

Comment: The right answer, of course... still curious though - why do you need a table alias, in a query on a single table?

Comment: Well, not any particular reason .. I find it more readable and it had become a habit ( a good one by the way:) @mathguy

Comment: ...but no column aliases? They would make more sense to me than the table alias in this very simple case.

Comment: My habit is about table aliases. Yes, it does make more sense to alias the aggregated columns, which only now I see is missing.

Comment: :-) Another good habit is to not use Oracle reserved words as column names/aliases. DESC is a reserved word; as written, the query will (or should) throw an error. (Of course, the OP had that in the original, which could be pointed out to them.)

Comment: Trust me, I never use Oracle reserved words, more like 50 Chars length of columns/tables :). I usually don't touch OP names of columns , because I assume occasionally they are changing the names for privacy issues , and they will just change them back. If not, they can work a bit by them self @mathguy

Answer (score 0):

If you know that only one row per column would have a value, you can use an aggregate function like `min` or `max` that would skip the `null`s and return the only value in the column. E.g.:

```
SELECT   id, year, code, MAX("desc"), MAX("year"), MAX(pid)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id, year, code
```

Comment: Thank you very much